# Do galaxies have a preferred orientation?

Tags: galaxy

This article: http://physicsworld.com/cws/article/news/2011/jul/25/was-the-universe-born-spinning asserts that the universe was "born spinning" and that there is a preferred rotation direction for galaxies in the universe.  My question is whether there is a preferred galaxy orientation in the universe, that is, whether there is a preferred plane for the galaxy disk?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but given that orientation is relative in space, how COULD there be a preferred direction?  When no one can say which way is up, who can say which way is clockwise?

Comment: You can compare the angular momentum vector of the plane of a disk galaxy to one another, so it's relative to one another.

Comment: galaxies seem to have a preferred orientation relative to their embedding large scale structure filaments http://arxiv.org/abs/1308.2816

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no evidence for that. That's either a systematic observation error, or a random result within usual statistical fluctuations, compare [this Q&A site](http://van.physics.illinois.edu/qa/listing.php?id=18609).

Comment: Please sum up your links, since they can go down eventually.